# Долгое время включение пк

Tags: windows, загрузка, bios

переустановил винду на пк, время запуска биос было 8,6 сек. Все работало хорошо, ставил только лицензионный софт и. т. д. Решил поставить торренты, если что антивирус есть, качал только с проверенных сайтов. Вроде вирусов нет а время загрузки аж 9,1. С чем это может быть связано, и как это устранить?

Comment: По-вашему лицензионный софт не может тормозить что ли?

Comment: Правильно ли я вас понимаю, что время загрузки увеличилось на 0,5сек и вас это сильно беспокоит?

Comment: Спиртом протирать пробовали?

Comment: Вы думаете, что чистая система должна загружаться с такой же скоростью, как и с программами? А ничего, что возрастает объём реестра, количество автозапускаемых программ, подключаемых библиотек и т.д.? И полсекунды - это вообще ни о чём.

Comment: Погрешность секундомера ⏱

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь: https://www.anekdot.ru/id/1092235/

Answer (score 1):

Устранить - никак.

Во первых, вы установили доп. софт (даже если официальный), из-за которого, о чудо, система начинает работать медленнее.

Во вторых, реестр через какое-то время тоже засоряется, что немаловажно.

А в третьих, 0.5 секунд - в принципе, смахивает на статистическую погрешность.

Вывод: если вас не устраивает время загрузки системы, купите по-быстрее SSD.